# Tableau Default Filter

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I need help with 3 things.

1. The Properties are in ASC order. But I need the property 'Market Average' to always be on top as the first one.
2. This property called Market Average has 0 beds and baths, as showin the 'Selected Floorplan Filter'. I'd like to remove the '0 Bed 0 Bath' from the filter list, just hide it, so noone can select it.
3. The hardest and most valuable one. The property names you see here are based on an ID in the query. When I change the ID in the parameter the property names will change to new ones. But one property name is constant, 'Market Average'. How do I make it so even though I switch IDs and new properties come in, Market Average is ALWAYS selected by default? Because what happens is that all new properties are either selected or unchecked on the properties filter.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tywhn.jpg

Comment: 1 question per question please